# How to force JULIA_PKG_DEVDIR on previously "dev'ed" packages

Tags: julia

I am attempting to change the location of my dev folder.

In my startup.jl file, I have put

```
ENV[JULIA_PKG_DEVDIR]= Path/To/Folder
```

I can check that this worked, as when I display ENV in the REPL, it reflects the changes. All good so far. The problem is that, when deving a new package, it is then placed in the old, default location.

Will I have to delete the default folder? Do I have to cu/copy/paste the old folder to the new location? does the new location have to be named a certain thing?

And as a side-bar, how can I get the previously dev'ed packages to the new location? Do I have to free and dev them again?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by deving a new package?

Comment: using 'Pkg.dev("PackageName")', or ']dev PackageName'